# Holomorphic function at a point

Tags: definition, riemann-surfaces

A map $f:X\to Y$ between Riemann surfaces is called holomorphic if for every complex charts $\varphi $ and $ \psi$ (of $X$ and $Y$ resp) we have that $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is holomorphic. I would like to know if there is a local definition of this i.e. I would like to know if given a map $f:X\to Y$ between Riemann surfaces and $ x\in X$ a point is there a notion of $f$ being holomorphic at $x$.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: The notion of “holomorphic” isn’t applied to points, but instead “complex differentiable”. Then you can define a function of Riemann surfaces $f \colon X → Y$ to be differentiable at $x$, if for any charts $φ$ on $X$ and $ψ$ on $Y$, $ψ ∘ f ∘ φ^{-1}$ is complex differentiable at $φ(x)$.

Comment: @k.stm: Typically "holomorphic at a point" is defined to mean "complex differentiable in a neighborhood of the point".

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, yeah. Makes sense. I like that.

Comment: @EricWofsey If you say so. I'd restrict "holomorphic" to open  sets; the standard  meaning of "analytic on E"  is "holomorphic in some nbd of E".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's just the obvious thing: $f$ is holomorphic at $x$ if whenever $\varphi$ is a complex chart of $X$ defined at $x$ and $\psi$ is a complex chart of $Y$ defined at $f(x)$, $\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is holomorphic at $\varphi(x)$.

Comment: Have you got a reference handy for this usage?

Comment: Nope.  I'm not sure I've ever actually seen it used, since typically the only reason to be interested in a function holomorphic at a point is for studying local properties and so there's no reason to talk about Riemann surfaces rather than just $\mathbb{C}$.  It's the obvious definition though and can be considered as a special case of the very general principle that any local property on Euclidean space gives rise to a corresponding local definition on manifolds.

Comment: "Obvious" doesn't make it an actual standard definition. I really don't believe the word is used except for open sets - "analytic'' is there to fill  the need for this use of "holomorphic'. (Really - if you've never seen it used how can you say that _is_ the definition?)

Comment: I have never seen "analytic" and "holomorphic" distinguished the way you say.  I have absolutely seen holomorphic functions on non-open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ though (I just don't specifically recall seeing it more generally on Riemann surfaces).  For instance, Stein and Shakarchi's _Complex Analysis_ defines holomorphic functions at a single point of $\mathbb{C}$, or more generally on closed subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: " the very general principle that any local property on Euclidean space gives rise to a corresponding local definition on manifolds" hmm, perhaps I haven't been clear. Yes of course if one did speak of "holomorphic at $x$" in a Euclidean context then the extension to Riemann surfaces would be exactly as you say. I'm asserting that there iis no "holomorphic at $x$" in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Also Wikipedia defines "holomorphic at a point" in $\mathbb{C}$ citing some other textbook: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function

Comment: I suppose claiming that _Complex Made Simple_ explicitly agrees would be silly. But for example Rudin never uses "holomorphic" except in an open set...

Comment: I certainly would not be surprised if different texts have different conventions about this.  The convention I am used to is that holomorphic and (complex) analytic are interchangeable and both can be used with non-open domains to mean complex-differentiable on a neighborhood.